# Considering the order of selection in case of principle of inclusion and exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion, stirling-numbers

I was going through the combinatorial problem finding number of ways to distribute $n$ distinguishable items to $r$ distinguishable groups. It turns out to be $r!S(n,r)$, where $S(n,r)$ is a Stirlings number of second kind. I got how it came. I realized that the whole solution is not taking into consideration the order of distribution. At first I didn't get why so. But after little bit of more thinking, I realized that Stirlings number is doing nothing but applying principle of inclusion and exclusion in series form. And principle of inclusion and exclusion does not take into consideration the order as it is applied in case of combinations/selections but not in case of permutations. **Q1.** Is it the reason we don't consider the order of distribution here?

**Q2.** Isn't it technically possible to take order of distribution too into consideration? For example, above distribution can be proves as follows:

- There are $(r-0)^n$ ways to distribute $n$ items to $r$ groups such that every one will get at least one item (no one get zero items which can be selected in ${}^rC_0=1$ ways).
- There are $(r-1)^n$ ways to distribute $n$ items to $(r-1)$ groups such that one group does not get any item which can be selected in ${}^rC_1$.
- There are $(r-2)^n$ ways to distribute $n$ items to $(r-2)$ groups such that two groups do not get any item which can be selected in  ${}^rC_2$.
- And so on.
- There are $(r-r)^n=0$ ways to distribute $n$ items to $(r-r)=0$ groups such that no group get any item which can be selected in ${}^rC_r$.

By the principle of inclusion and exclusion, the desired count is
$${}^rC_0(r-0)^n-{}^rC_1(r-1)^n+{}^rC_2(r-2)^n-...\pm {}^rC_r(r-r)^n\hspace{1 cm}...(I)$$
$$=(-1)^0\times{}^rC_0(r-0)^n+(-1)^1\times{}^rC_1(r-1)^n+(-1)^2\times{}^rC_2(r-2)^n-...+(-1)^r\times{}^rC_r(r-r)^n$$
$$=\Sigma_{i=0}^r(-1)^i\times{}^rC_i(r-i)^n$$
$$=r!\frac{1}{r!}\Sigma_{i=0}^r(-1)^i\times{}^rC_i(r-i)^n$$
$$=r!S(n,r)$$

If here we have to take order into consideration, then equation $(I)$ would have been

$${}^rC_0(r-0)^n\color{red}{r!}-{}^rC_1(r-1)^n\color{red}{(r-1)!}+{}^rC_2(r-2)^n\color{red}{(r-2)!}-...\pm {}^rC_r(r-r)^n\color{red}{(r-r)!}$$

Am I correct with this?

**Q3.** If I am correct in Q2, why no one talks about principle of inclusion-exclusion or distribution of distinguishable objects to distinguishable groups with distribution (or selection) order into consideration? (I almost never came across such problem)

Comment: After reading the question several times I have decided that I don't really know precisely what it is asking so have decided to delete my answer.  I can only speculate that such an ordered distribution process would count a different kind of combinatorial object, what form that object may take (if any) I'm  afraid I cannot say. Perhaps another mathSE user will be of more help than I.

Comment: Hi again, was giving some more thoughts to this. I felt that when order of selection is taken into consideration, it will be simply $n!r!S(n,r)$. For example for $n=3$ and $r=2$, the different distributions would be $\{(1,23)(23,1)(2,13)(13,2)(3,12)(12,3)\}$. Total $r!S(n,r)=6$. When order of item selection is taken into consideration, each of those distributions can happen in $3!$ ways depending upon $3!$ different selections $\{123,132,213,231,312,321\}$ thus giving total $n!r!S(n,r)=36$ distributions. Does this makes sense? Also do you find any significance in considering selection order?

Comment: It does make sense I think. If I were to interpret it I would consider a two-stage process in which the balls are randomly ordered in stage 1 then they are distributed into boxes in stage 2. I cannot imediately think of a natural example of when this happens but I would start with this process.